# fullcalendar dragged event not visible in getEventSources

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have a fullcalendar Calendar loaded on a HTML page with some draggable events. I can drag and postition them on my calendar, but I'm trying to retrieve those events positioned to be saved in my database thanks to a "Save button" with the following code:

```
function saveEvents(){

obj = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getEventSources');
console.log("Events: "+JSON.decycle(obj));

$.ajax({
type: 'get',
url: 'setCalendarServlet',
dataType: 'JSON',
data: { 
  loadProds: 1,
  json: JSON.stringify(JSON.decycle(obj))
},
success: function(data) {

},
error: function(data) {
}
});
```

with HTML code:

```
<body>
<div id='wrap'>

    <div id='external-events'>
        <h4>Evenements</h4>
        <div class='fc-event'>event 1</div>
        <div class='fc-event'>event 2</div>
    </div>
    <a class="btn btn-default" href="javascript:saveEvents();">save</a>
    <div id='calendar'></div>

    <div style='clear:both'></div>

</div>
```

but when I retrieve `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('getEventSources');` I do not get my freshly dragged events...

I tried to refresh my events by using:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'rerenderEvents' );
```

or 
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );

but I have the same result...

how can I get them in my object ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the solution....

just retrieve events with the following line:

```
obj = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
```

instead of `getEventSources`
. hope it will help...